# Adding missing rows using multidplyr

Tags: r

I'm trying to add missing rows to the following dataframe.

```
df = data.frame(DATE = as.Date(c("2016-05-31", "2016-08-31", "2016-10-31", "2016-07-31", "2016-08-31", "2016-10-31", "2016-12-31")), 
            KONTR = c("122","122","122","553","553","102","102"),
            KAP = as.double(1:7),
            DIV =c("PI","PI","PI","OP","OP","PR","PR"))
```

This code works

```
result = df %>%
  group_by(KONTR) %>%
  do(left_join(data.frame(KONTR = .$KONTR[1], DATE = seq(min(.$DATE)+1, max(.$DATE)+1, by="1 month")-1), ., 
           by=c("KONTR", "DATE")))
```

but as my real dataframe has 1.5m rows it takes more than 15 minutes to complete. I tried to use multidplyr with following code but I get error and I dont know what's wrong.

```
cluster <- create_cluster(3)

by_kontr <- df %>% partition(KONTR,cluster=cluster)

result = by_kontr %>%
  group_by(KONTR) %>%
  do(left_join(data.frame(KONTR = .$KONTR[1], DATE = seq(min(.$DATE)+1, max(.$DATE)+1, by="1 month")-1), ., 
           by=c("KONTR", "DATE")))

Error in checkForRemoteErrors(lapply(cl, recvResult)) : 
  3 nodes produced errors; first error: could not find function "left_join"
```

Comment: Please load the `library(dplyr)`

Comment: dplyr is loaded

Comment: Please show all the packages used.  We don't know which package has functions `partition` etc

Comment: @akrun I only use dplyr and multidplyr packages

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution. Library attachment is required at slave level so I have to add to my code following line:

```
cluster_eval(cluster,library(dplyr))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another options are register in advance the library you are going to use

```
multidplyr::cluster_library(cluster, "dplyr")

by_kontr %>%
group_by(KONTR) %>%
do(left_join(data.frame(KONTR = .$KONTR[1], DATE = seq(min(.$DATE)+1, max(.$DATE)+1, by="1 month")-1), ., by=c("KONTR", "DATE")))
```

Or write `package::function` inside the `do` command. I.e., instead of `left_join` you write `dplyr::left_join`

```
by_kontr %>%
group_by(KONTR) %>%
do(dplyr::left_join(data.frame(KONTR = .$KONTR[1], DATE = seq(min(.$DATE)+1, max(.$DATE)+1, by="1 month")-1), ., by=c("KONTR", "DATE")))
```